# get live price in milliseconds (Binance Websocket)

Tags: python, api, websocket, bitcoin, binance

how can i change my code so i get the informations every 100 milliseconds ?

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager


async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts = bm.trade_socket('BTCBUSD')
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res)

    await client.close_connection()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

i apperciate every answer i can get , thanks a lot !

Comment: how many milliseconds is it getting the information at the moment? also i think the fastest you can get is 200 ~ 300 ms due to the limits set by the exchange

Comment: It seems like I’m getting data every 2 seconds .getting data every 200ms would be great . You know maybe how I can do that ?

Comment: yes, i'll write something up for you over the weekend.

Comment: Thank u so much . I’m waiting for that as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@bookTicker") as ws:
        while True:
            response = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=2)
            response=json.loads(response)
            print(response)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about "how to get live price in milliseconds (Binance Websocket)"

Here is a list of available streams on binance with the available options for "update speed": https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#detailed-stream-information

For my understand most stream types are updating once a second (update speed: 1000ms).

Only depth streams are possible to update 10 times per second (1000ms and 100ms interval)

Trade streams (agg and normal) and Bookticker (individual and all) are in real time. That means, as soon this info is available, you will receive it...

If there is no trade, you will not receive anything, because there is no change in price... but as soon a trade happens, it will get reported to you.

If you want to know, the current buy and sell price for that an asset is available you can use the bookticker which is much less data compared to depth and diff. depth streams... if you need more than the first positions of the current orderbook i recommend using a local depth cache: https://www.lucit.tech/unicorn-binance-local-depth-cache.html

To get a stable websocket connection i recommend using [UNICORN Binance WebSocket API](https://www.lucit.tech/unicorn-binance-websocket-api.html), it catches most exceptions and reconnects automatically after a disconnect, it uses asyncio inside (callback function is inside an event loop) and the syntax to use it is easy:

```
from unicorn_binance_websocket_api.manager import BinanceWebSocketApiManager


def process_new_receives(stream_data, stream_buffer_name=False):
    print(str(stream_data))


ubwa = BinanceWebSocketApiManager(exchange="binance.com")
ubwa.create_stream('trade',
                   ['ethbtc', 'btcusdt', 'bnbbtc', 'ethbtc'],
                   process_stream_data=process_new_receives)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get realtime PRICE via websockets from the exchange ? Is it possible to filter the OB or the OB symbol ticker to get just and only the price ? Thanks

Comment: Bookticker doesn't give accurate price information. If you check the price on Spot trade on binance you'll see 2 different prices. Use aggTrade for real time price updates or miniTicker (1 second ticker)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem in a rush, below is what I use although I'm using the `websockets` library to make the calls. I'll take a look at the binance api when I have some more time to see if I can get the calls to be faster but this should hopefully achieve what you want.

You can change the delay between the requests by changing the time of sleep in `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` but if you put it any lower than 0.5 seconds it will  trigger an error: `received 1008 (policy violation) Too many requests; then sent 1008 (policy violation) Too many requests`

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

msg = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params":
        [
        "btcusdt@depth"
        ],
        "id": 1
        }

async def call_api():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth') as ws:
        while True:
            await ws.send(json.dumps(msg))
            response = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=2)
            response = json.loads(response)
            print(response)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api())
```

Comment: Hello my dear, thank u so much for your help. the coce runs only for about 2 minutes tghen i get an Error :/

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: this one : websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: sent 1011 (unexpected error) keepalive ping timeout; no close frame received